# Connection to firestore timing out , happening suddenly since today after working well

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been connecting to Google Firestore NoSQL database from my javascript project.
It worked well since yesterday.
Suddenly the connection to firestore is throwing time out error.

Here is the error in console .

https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?database=projects%2F......................... net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

[2020-11-14T18:31:33.525Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.0.1): Connection WebChannel transport errored: dr {type: "c", target: lr, a: lr, defaultPrevented: false, status: 1}

Why is this happening , I am totally clueless on this.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question like a minimal reproducible code? This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxSwhRSHeDQ&feature=emb_logo) can be helpful when asking.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on the same problem, after re-reading the docs and checking my code i noticed no differences.

After that i realised there was a chrome plug-in installed called "CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin". This is causing the issue

Haven't been successful yet with whitelisting the correct domain.

Hope this steers you into the right direction